# Checking directory or file from external owned server

Tags: php, linux, nusoap

I am developing  a script  for a music company in PHP that has different servers so they need to display a file if it exists or not  on the external server

like they have  3 versions of each music file    mp3  mp4  etc ..... and they are accessing the files (each version ) from there specific external server  . i have made three solutions for it all of them worked like charm but they are making the server slow .

**First Method** :

```
$handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

/* Get the HTML or whatever is linked in $url. */
$response = curl_exec($handle);

/* Check for 404 (file not found). */
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if($httpCode == 404) {
    /* Handle 404 here. */
}

curl_close($handle);

/* Handle $response here. */
```

**Second Method** : Using NuSOAP i made an api which checks internally the file and returns yes/no

**Third Method**:

```
function checkurl($url)
{
    return true;
    $file_headers = @get_headers($url);
    //var_dump($file_headers);

    if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily' || $file_headers[0] =='HTTP/1.1 302 Found') {
        $exists = false;

    }
    else {
        $exists = true;
    }
    return $exists;
}
```

So i need a solution that doesn't makes the server slow  any suggestions

Comment: Can't you just call file_exists... And it might make sense to cache results.

Comment: i dont think file_exists work for external servers its just for local
i think i have tried that first when starting this script

Comment: You have to work on JQuery Ajax Calling from External server to Internal Server checking existence of folder

Comment: Ill research on that as well

Comment: Can you cache the results of the lookup locally so the next time the file is requested you don't have to call out to the external servers, second if you are making multiple requests per page you can use curl_multi which allows you to make several concurrent requests which is typically faster then making the request serially

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought it works with above answers but it wasnt working where there were too many requests so i finally try again and again and found this solution its working perfectly actually the problem was redirects too many of them  so i  set time_out 15 in curl and it worked

```
                        $ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,            $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,         true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY,         true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        15);

$r = curl_exec($ch);
$r = split("\n", $r);
var_dump($r);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Be sure to issue a HEAD request, not GET**, since you don't want to get the file contents. And maybe you need to follow redirects, or not...

Example with curl (thanks to [this blog post](http://schlitt.info/opensource/blog/0606_sending_head_requests_with_extcurl.html)):

```
<?php
$url = 'http://localhost/c.txt';

echo "\n checking: $url";

$c = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt( $c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true ); 
curl_setopt( $c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true ); 
curl_setopt( $c, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5 ); 
curl_setopt( $c, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'HEAD' ); 
curl_setopt( $c, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1 ); 
curl_setopt( $c, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true ); 
curl_setopt( $c, CURLOPT_URL, $url ); 
$res = curl_exec( $c );

echo "\n\ncurl:\n";
var_dump($res);

echo "\nis 200: ";
var_dump(false !== strpos($res, 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK'));
```

SOAP or other web service implementation can be an option if the file is not available by HTTP.

If you want to use get_headers(), please note that by default [it's slow because it issues a GET request](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php#104723). To use HEAD request, you should change the default stream context (please check get_headers() on php manual):

```
stream_context_set_default(
    array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'HEAD'
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: if you can see my third method i am getting request with headers also but it doesnt solve the issue of sever being too slow

Comment: Your curl and get_headers() examples issue a GET request, which means that all the contens of the file is transferred. I've updated the answer.

Comment: The HEAD HTTP request gets only the headers that would result for a GET request: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HEAD_%28HTTP%29#Request_methods.